# Transform JavaScript array using key/code

Tags: javascript

I need help with a function that can transform array A to array B in JavaScript

Array A:

```
[ { id: 'U125H069G', code: 'C13LKL4V6' },
  { id: 'U13MPMLA3', code: 'C13LKL4V6' },
  { id: 'U125H069G', code: 'C125H083C' },
  { id: 'U13MPMLA3', code: 'C125H083C' },
  { id: 'U125H069G', code: 'C123Q00D9' },
  { id: 'U13MPMLA3', code: 'C123Q00D9' },
  { id: 'U125H069G', code: 'C13LM1VUP' } ]
```

Array B:

```
[{'id':'U125H069G', codes: ['C13LKL4V6','C125H083C','C123Q00D9', 'C13LM1VUP]},
  {'id':'U13MPMLA3': codes: ['C13LKL4V6','C125H083C','C123Q00D9']}]
```

Comment: This is kind of a basic, but tedious, programming exercise. Have you at least attempted something yourself you are having difficulty with? Maybe if you post what you have so far someone might be willing to help you rather than just flat out do all the work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically just loop through them, add an object to B when you find a new id or add an entry to the codes array if the id already exists.

```js
var A = [ { id: 'U125H069G', code: 'C13LKL4V6' },
      { id: 'U13MPMLA3', code: 'C13LKL4V6' },
      { id: 'U125H069G', code: 'C125H083C' },
      { id: 'U13MPMLA3', code: 'C125H083C' },
      { id: 'U125H069G', code: 'C123Q00D9' },
      { id: 'U13MPMLA3', code: 'C123Q00D9' },
      { id: 'U125H069G', code: 'C13LM1VUP' } ];
B = [];
A.forEach(function(va){
    if (!B.some(function(vb, i){
        if (vb.id === va.id){
            B[i].codes.push(va.code);
            return true;
        }
    })){
        B.push({id:va.id, codes:[va.code]})
    }
});
//Display
document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode(JSON.stringify(B)));
```

[forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)
[some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

Answer (score 1):

Your designed object should be

```
{'id':'U125H069G', codes: ['C13LKL4V6','C125H083C','C123Q00D9', 'C13LM1VUP']}
```

instead of

```
{'id':'U125H069G', codes: {'C13LKL4V6','C125H083C','C123Q00D9', 'C13LM1VUP'}}
```

Try like this

```
var temp = [];

data.forEach(function(x) {
  if (temp.map(function(y) {
      return y.id
    }).indexOf(x.id) < 0) {
    var codes = data.filter(function(z) {
      return z.id == x.id;
    }).map(function(z) {
      return z.code;
    });
    temp.push({
      id: x.id,
      codes: codes
    });
  }
})

console.log(temp);
```

<kbd>**[`DEMO`](https://jsfiddle.net/ubecacns/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

Run it through a forEach and store unique ids in an object map.

```js
var input = [ 
  { id: 'U125H069G', code: 'C13LKL4V6' },
  { id: 'U13MPMLA3', code: 'C13LKL4V6' },
  { id: 'U125H069G', code: 'C125H083C' },
  { id: 'U13MPMLA3', code: 'C125H083C' },
  { id: 'U125H069G', code: 'C123Q00D9' },
  { id: 'U13MPMLA3', code: 'C123Q00D9' },
  { id: 'U125H069G', code: 'C13LM1VUP' } 
];

var idMap={};
var output =[];

input.forEach(function(value, index, arr) {
  
    if(!idMap[value.id]) {
        idMap[value.id] = { id: value.id, codes:[value.code]};  
        output.push(idMap[value.id]);
    }
    else {
        idMap[value.id].codes.push(value.code);
    }  
  
}); 

console.log(output);
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(output);

/*[{'id':'U125H069G', codes: {'C13LKL4V6','C125H083C','C123Q00D9', 'C13LM1VUP}},
  {'id':'U13MPMLA3': codes: {'C13LKL4V6','C125H083C','C123Q00D9'}}]
  */
```

```html
<textarea id="output" rows="10" cols=80>
    
</textarea>
```